# Making website (map, props and other newbie things)

Tags: reactjs

Hello i followed tutorial and i dont know where it goes wrong. Please help. It says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". I include 2 files, take alook.

```
state={
    products: storeProducts
}

render(){
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="py-5">
            <div className="container">
            <Title name="our" title="products"/>
            <div className="row">
            <ProductConsumer>
            {value=>{
                return value.products.map(product=>{
                    return <Product key={product.id} product={product}/>
                });
                }}
            </ProductConsumer>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

}

```
handleDetail=()=>{
    console.log('hello from detail')
}
addToCart=()=>{
    console.log('hello from add to cart')
}
render(){
    return(
        <ProductContext.Provider value={{
            ...this.state,
            handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
            addToCart: this.addToCart,
        }}>
        {this.props.children}
        </ProductContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

}

const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export {ProductProvider, ProductConsumer}

Comment: Can you please put the value of this.state here?

Comment: `return value.products.map` instead of `value` use `this.state`